# Attribute selection methods Weka

Tags: dataset, weka, data-mining

I want to make an attribute selection using the methods

- relief
- gainr
- infog
- cfs

but I cannot select the `gainr` and `infog` methods from `weka`.
Does anybody has any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

While you're not providing much information to go off of, the main difference between the `CfsSubsetEval` and `ReliefFAttributeEval` and the `GainRatioAttributeEval` and `InfoGainAttributeEval` evaluators appears to be that the former two have the capabilities to process *Numeric* and *Date* classes, whereas the latter two do not. If you are trying to process either of those two classes, this could explain your problem.